# Oracle PL SQL STRING Functions

Tags: sql, string, oracle, function

I have a column which has values or rows as combination of name & Code as seen below.

Data_Current

```
Column_X
---------------------------
Saint_Peter_King_Jr_0001
Kishore_Prasad_Misra_1253
George_Floyd_21543
Veer_Venkata_Sai_Narsimha_Kishore_00015
```

and I want to get Name & Code in different column but the separator '_' and its occurrence(Count & Position) is not same in every row or value as seen above.

So how to read the string from the right and extract the name & Code as below

Result Required

```
Name                                    Code
---------------------------------------------
Saint_Peter_King_Jr                      0001
Kishore_Prasad_Misra                     1253
George_Floyd                            21543
Veer_Venkata_Sai_Narsimha_Kishore       00015
```

I tried but `instr` function but `INSTR( string, substring [, start_position [, th_appearance ] ] )` but the appearance is not constant and changes based on name. How to make it dynamic?

Comment: Of course the difficulty would be completely eliminated if you were to fix your seriously  flawed data model.  "name" and "code" should be two separate columns.  Your current design violates standard Third Normal Form design, which is the heart of relational data design.

Answer (score 1):

Below SQL uses Oracle built-in functions [INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/INSTR.html#GUID-47E3A7C4-ED72-458D-A1FA-25A9AD3BE113) and [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E) and assumes that the "code" is always the last part of the string and is always preceded by a single, underscore character, i.e. `_`

```sql
select substr('Veer_Venkata_Sai_Narsimha_Kishore_00015',1,instr('Veer_Venkata_Sai_Narsimha_Kishore_00015','_',-1) - 1) as NAME
      ,substr('Veer_Venkata_Sai_Narsimha_Kishore_00015',instr('Veer_Venkata_Sai_Narsimha_Kishore_00015','_',-1) + 1) as CODE
  from dual
```

Result is...

```
NAME                              CODE
--------------------------------- -----
Veer_Venkata_Sai_Narsimha_Kishore 00015
```

Note that you may substitute the column name, i.e. `Column_X` for the string literal.

Comment: Hi Abra, Wonderful and thanks a ton. It worked. -1 after the separator worked perfectly. without -1 it is reading from left but with -1 it is reading from right. great.

Answer (score 1):

The regexp_substr method.  The with statement just sets up the data, the meat is in the select.  The regular expressions handle what you mean by dynamic, i.e. an unknown number of characters of code and/or an unknown number of numbers in the code.  The parenthesis in the regular expression define a captured group, which is returned.  For the name, the set of any characters before the last underscore followed by 1 or more digits, and for the code, the set of 1 or more digits after any number of any characters and the last underscore.

```
WITH tbl(column_X) AS (
  SELECT 'Saint_Peter_King_Jr_0001' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kishore_Prasad_Misra_1253' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'George_Floyd_21543' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Veer_Venkata_Sai_Narsimha_Kishore_00015' FROM dual
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_X, '(.*?)_\d+', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS NAME,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_X, '.*?_(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS code
FROM tbl;

NAME                                    CODE                                   
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
Saint_Peter_King_Jr                     0001                                   
Kishore_Prasad_Misra                    1253                                   
George_Floyd                            21543                                  
Veer_Venkata_Sai_Narsimha_Kishore       00015                                  

4 rows selected.
```

Comment: Hi Gary, There are numerous records and not just 4, its too difficult to add select query for all the records.

Comment: @kiss.shoremishra Please note the WITH is called a CTE for Common Table Expression and here is used to create a data set for the example.  The select below the CTE is applied to that data set for the example.  You would only use the select below and the FROM clause would be your actual table.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that with built in functions. You are going to have to write your own function to tackle it procedurally.